# Html <img> Tag - Space between the Image and an css-Border (with or without border-radius)

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have a question regarding the img tag.

I want to display a profile picture with rounded borders. The size of my image is 40px by 40px. Strangely though, there is a gap appearing between the actual image and the css border. Even stranger, the gap increases or decreases, depending on the zoom of my Browser. I'm using chrome, but tested with Edge, as well.

## Screenshots

[100% Zoom - White Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3CVN.png)

[125% Zoom - (Almost) no white Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ksy.png)

[150% Zoom - White Gap (Again -.-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owRc8.png)

## Code

Currently I am having an img tag inside a div container with rounded corners and overflow: hidden. Additionally I tried to have a border directly on the image tag, but it wouldn't work, either.

Before you ask: **I also tried without any border-radius.** Unfortunately it didn't work, as well.

### Html

```
<div class="div_profile_picture">
   <img class="profile_picture" src="" alt="" #profilePicture>
</div>
```

The source is assigned via Javascript (Angular)

### CSS

```
.div_profile_picture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 2px solid var(--red_main);
  border-radius: 10px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 2px var(--red_main);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile_picture {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;

  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
}
```

As you might see, I tried several different solutions, I found online, too. :)

I really hope, somebody can help me, it's driving me crazy...

Thanks for your answers in advance!

## Update

It seems it is a bug in Chrome, only at for certain setups...
Unfortunately I don't know any fix for this, but if I'm able to find one, I will update this post.

Comment: Sounds like pixel rounding or ant-aliasing

Comment: Is there something, I can do about, then?

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before on SO so you might try searching. I seem to recall that a small `transform` somethings fixes it but that will be found in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying the border-radius property directly to the *profile_picture* img tag and removing the *object-fit* property. Resizing the image will show the entire picture.

```css
.div_profile_picture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 2px solid var(--red_main);
  border-radius: 10px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 2px var(--red_main);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile_picture {
  display: block;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_profile_picture">
   <img class="profile_picture" src="" alt="" #profilePicture>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Unfortunately this trick hasn't chagend it for me..